# Question about permutations and or combinations

Tags: python-3.x, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Out of given list of values I want to get all combinations in a given length, like:

```
given_list = [a,b]
given_lenght_of_combinations = 3
```

Expected output:

```
a,a,a
a,a,b
a,b,a
a,b,b
b,a,a
.
.
.
b,b,b
b,b,a
b,a,b
b,a,a
  .
  .
  .
```

I played around with permutations and combinations from itertools but couldn't get it worked.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t permutations or combinations—it’s Cartesian product. Fortunately, there’s still a way to make that in `itertools`: [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
itertools.product(given_list, repeat=given_length_of_combinations)
```